# Python: neural net cost function stuck at ln(2)

Tags: python, neural-network

Was just wondering if anyone else has encountered this behavior before. I couldn't find this specific issue being brought up in my searches. I wrote my own neural net (a very simple one) using just numpy, and it appears to work, the cost function decreases as I iterate over it. However, when I change the random initialization on the weights from using np.random.randn(shape) to np.random.randn(shape)*0.01 (I heard that using smaller initial weights might speed up learning because I'm using a sigmoid layer), my cost function starts at .69~ln(2) and pretty much gets stuck there. This happens no matter how many times I restart the neural net, and no matter what kind of inputs I'm putting into it. I find this very odd indeed. I should add, that if I start off without the 0.01 multiplication factor, the cost function will decrease to less than .69.

The neural net uses a cross-entropy cost function, and uses gradient descent to make steps. No regularization has been implemented. This behavior doesn't seem to depend on what the neural network's dimensions (number of layers, neurons per layer) are, or the learning rate, only on whether I initialize the starting weights with or without multiplying them by 0.01.

Comment: It might be a bug in your implementation, or even normal behaviour given the choices you have made for cost function, activation functions etc. Although your error seems quite specific I cannot imagine what the root cause is. You will need to share your code - and data or data generation that is causing the network to "stick" - before anyone could be certain what the problem is.

Comment: I was just wondering if someone had some experience and has seen something similar. I've done a bit of debugging to see what's happening. Basically, the cost function gets stuck at ln(2) because all of the weights in the early layers have all been crushed to ~0 (something like 1e-203), so the neural net has essentially given up on trying to calculate anything and is just telling the final sigmoid layer to output .5 no matter what the input is. I added a little bit of regularization to the gradient descent and this phenomenon happens as well.

Comment: In fact, if my inputs and outputs are all just totally random numbers, this would be the ideal result...getting 50% accuracy. Maybe...maybe my inputs and outputs are not correlated like I thought they were...maybe they are essentially random... it still seems odd that simply multiplying my weights by 0.01 gets me to this optimum but not multiplying my weights by 0.01 allows my model to overfit the training data though. Also, even for regularization with lambda=0.01, the cost function gets stuck at .69...very odd...

Comment: You say: "I was just wondering if someone had some experience and has seen something similar". However, in my experience with something as complex as a neural network, this rarely will point to a correct fix - at best it will be guesses on what you might want to look at. The approach that will work and get you an explanation as to what went wrong is to have someone help debug your code.

Comment: Ok understood. I just didn't want to post like 400 lines of code and then just ask you guys to look through it for me and help me debug or something like that (that would be asking you to do my job for me). Was wondering if there was some general experience that applied in this instance to maybe help me debug it myself. I'll try to debug this myself first. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, 400 lines would be a bit much. You can usually fit a basic NN, even implemented in Numpy, into much less though, maybe just 100 lines. Here's a reference to one of mine, maybe it will help you spot a problem: https://github.com/neilslater/nn_practice/blob/master/01_basic_mlp/mlp_numpy.py

Comment: After a full 2 days of debugging, I think I figured out the issue. I had some ints mixed with floats somewhere, and it was killing off the gradient, setting them all to 0 apparently when the weights were set too small. This issue was so difficult to debug. I implemented gradient checking and even then, everything seemed fine for quite several iterations before an error showed up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for posting an update, and cool that you found your bug. I really don't think anyone could have guessed that specific issue from your description alone.